# Upgrade existing custom angular Filter using upgrade module

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am using angular's upgrade module to create a hybrid app where both angular js and angular2 can co-exist together.I have a situation here 
where i need a existing custom filter to be used for a component.Does the upgrade module support upgrading custom filters.Ifsd so please advice how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately upgrade module doesn't support upgrading filters to Pipes. But Pipes are very similar to filters and are really easy to upgrade manually.

If you need to have co-existing filter & Pipe I suggest to extract all logic & transforms to simple TypeScript / JavaScript:

```
export class PipeUtils {
    static myFilterTransform(value, ...args) {
        // return transformed value
    }
}
```

AngularJS filter:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.filter('myFilter', () => PipeUtils.myFilterTransform)
```

Angular Pipe:

```
export class MyPipe {
    transform(value, ...args) {
        return PipeUtils.myFilterTransform(value, ...args)
    }
}
```